# Bayes' Theorem to find the probability that the stock will go up.

Tags: probability, combinations, bayesian, bayes-theorem

An investment company analyses stocks and predicts whether their price will go up or down. So
far, half of the stocks analysed by the company have gone up, 3/4 of the stocks that went up were
correctly predicted to go up, and 2/5 of the stocks that went down were incorrectly predicted to
go up. Suppose that the company tells you that it will go up. Compute the probability that the
stock will indeed go up.

**My Solution:**

Let A denotes "Stock will go up "

Let B denotes "Company tells that the stock will go up"

Now, we need to find **P(A | B)**

P(A|B)= P(B|A).P(A)/P(B)

P(B) = P(B|A).P(A) + P(B|A').P(A')
    = (3/4)(0.5)   +  (2/5)(0.5)

Please tell me if this is correct.

Comment: It appears correct yes.

Comment: Though you have not completed the calculation

Comment: @Henry I will complete that. I just wanted to know the approach and if I have used the theorem correctly. What do you think?

Comment: That is indeed a version of Bayes theorem $\mathbb P(A \mid B)=\dfrac{\mathbb P(B \mid A) \mathbb P(A)}{\mathbb P(B \mid A) \mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B \mid A') \mathbb P(A')}$

Comment: @Henry Yes, you are right. Here, I wanted to check if I have denoted the events, A and B correctly. Because I usually denote them wrong and arrive at the wrong answer.